# Dynamic calculator driven by MathML, LaTex, or

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

All,

I'm in the process of building a web application (C#, MVC3 Razor) which will need to support entry of mathematical formulas. I know there are a number of good JavaScript libraries to do this. My current question has to do with the other end.

After users have entered formulas they need to interact with them in a dynamic calculator. The math is never significantly complex. Just the four big operations (+, -, *, /). And the formulas aren't going to be overly long.

I can't help but feeling someone must have solved this problem before. Anyone know of anything?

Some additional requirements:
 - Ability to plug constants known to the system into a formula.
 - Ability to indicate a value is based upon two others which are used to read from a reference table. (In other words user enters a 5 and a 20, system goes to a table and knows that in such a case the value 3.2 should be used in the formula.)

I fully expect I'll have some customizing to do. So close and flexible is good enough.

To boil the problem down:
 - Input: A formula in some known format/markup
 - Process: Conversion into mathematical symbols and markers for inputs
 - Render: User interactive calculator allowing users to input values and get output defined by the formula.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll take a closer look. It may get me closer to where I need to be. One nice part is whatever markup I end up using really should be easy to convert to a simple hand written equation, which is what it seems NCalc wants. Have you used it, or just know of it? (P.S. I'd vote up your answer but I don't have the cred yet. Not sure if it's "the" answer yet so...)